# Hive and regular expression

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to filter all the ip adresses in a username. But this doesnt really work properly in my query:

```
select distinct regexp_extract(username, '^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})$', 0) from ips.
```

The problem is that he even recognizes numbers as 1000000 as ip adress.
Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You need extra backslashes to escape special characters like . or \s. There's some more info on the wiki at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Try something like:

```
select
    distinct regexp_extract(ip, '^([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})$', 0) as match
from
    ips
having
    match <> "";
```

Comment: Not to be pendantic, but wouldn't you write: `'^([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$'` to be shorter?