# how to grab an element in a string in hive?

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table called datatable like this:

```
columnA   columnB
1         1^1^4~3^4^2~4^9^a
2         4^2^2~8^9^a~1^1^1
```

I want to be able to search the elements of an array and operate on it.  In this case, I need to find the first number before the `a` in each set between the `~`.  So, the output should look like this:

```
columnA   columnB
1         4
2         8
```

How do I express this in `HIVEQL`?  Right now, I know how to split on the `~`:

`select columnA, split(columnB, '~') from datatable`  but...I don't know how to program it to grab the element from group containing "`a`".  How do I do this?

I'm trying to avoid regular expressions, but I realize they might be needed here....

Comment: Try `select columnA, regexp_replace(columnB, ".*?([0-9]+)[^~]*a.*", "$1") from datatable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expressions seem to be pretty handy in your case. The one extracting first numbers in an `a`-featured group is:

```
(\d+)\^(?:\d+\^)*a
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rL8gV3/1

And the query would be:

```
select columnA, regexp_extract(columnB, '(\\d+)\\^(?:\\d+\\^)*a', 1) from datatable
```

Comment: Why do you escape twice in the query but not in the regex?

Comment: Backslashes need to be escaped in HIVEQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289445/hive-and-regular-expression